# Random document from a collection in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to create a `Schema.statics.random` function that gets me a random element from the collection. I know there is an example for the native MongoDB driver, but I can't get it working in Mongoose.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found this Mongoose Schema static function in a GitHub Gist, which should achieve what you are after. It counts number of documents in the collection and then returns one document after skipping a random amount.

```
QuoteSchema.statics.random = function(callback) {
  this.count(function(err, count) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
    this.findOne().skip(rand).exec(callback);
  }.bind(this));
};
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/3453567

***NB*** I modified the code a bit to make it more readable.

Comment: Cool. You know how this could be transalted to CoffeeScript?

Comment: Okay, it didn't work, so I wasn't sure (that was the problem in first case), but since I still face the problem with inline Javscript. It's rather strange. The stuff inside function(callback) { } is never called. Maybe some problem with the DB-Connection. I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Hmm, it's strange. The callback never gets called.

Comment: I've tested it and it works fine. Could you post your entire schema and I'll see if there's something I can see?

Comment: Well, it is working. Just somehow connecting to a remote server doesn't work.

Comment: It all came down to my development machine. So if anyone ever has the same problem: Set up another system. ;)

Comment: 1. Ewww coffee script, 2. they have js to coffee script online converters, just a google away

Answer (score 23):

If you are not wanting to add "test like" code into your schema, this uses Mongoose queries.

```
Model.count().exec(function(err, count){

  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);

  Model.findOne().skip(random).exec(
    function (err, result) {

      // result is random 

  });

});
```

Comment: I found this really easy to implement

Comment: How about multiple documents in one query. Is there an easier solution other than querying multiple times?

Comment: @codersaif This is not what you'd want to use for that. The skip function is directed at pagination and is a cursor, [mongodb cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/). This will move the cursor to a specific position and is meant to read forward. The code in my answer is basically pagination, `Model.findOne().skip(100).limit(1).exec()` but is fetching a single document.

Comment: @PrathameshMore 1)`Model.count()` retrieves how many documents are actually in the collection. 2) `Math....` gets a random whole number within the range of documents counted. 3) Finally we hit mongo one more time with the `findOne()` using the `skip` function to get a single document indexed to the random number in range.

Comment: What if I want to fetch 10 documents from the database? How can I implement this?

Answer (score 19):

A shorter and *maybe* more performant solution
(we don't iterate through the collection once to count and a second time to skip elements, but mongoose might do that behind the scenes):

Use [aggregate and $sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#pipe._S_sample):

```
Model.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 } }])
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use aggregate:

```
User.aggregate([
    {$match: {gender: "male"}},
    {$sample: {size: 10}}
], function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
});
```

Or you can use npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-simple-random

```
User.findRandom({gender: "male"}, {}, {limit: 10}, function(err, results) { 
    console.log(results); // 10 elements
});
```

Comment: this should be marked as the answer

Answer (score 6):

I've implemented a plugin for mongoose that does this in a very efficient way using a $near query on two randomly generated coordinates using a 2dsphere index. Check it out here: https://github.com/matomesc/mongoose-random.

Answer (score 3):

For people looking at this in times of async/await, promises etc.:

```
MySchema.statics.random = async function() {
  const count = await this.count();
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
  const randomDoc = await this.findOne().skip(rand);
  return randomDoc;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays [Model.estimatedDocumentCount()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.estimatedDocumentCount) is recommended. For the Model called `Item` an outline of a function would be:

```
const Item = require('../your/path/to/Model/Item')

async function getRandomItem() {
   const numItems = await Item.estimatedDocumentCount()
   const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * numItems)
   const randomItem = await Item.findOne().skip(rand)
   return randomItem
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Getting estimated document count.
yourModel.estimatedDocumentCount().then((count) => {
  //Random number between 0 and count.
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);

  // Finding ONE random document.
  yourModel
    .findOne()
    .skip(rand)
    .then((randomDocument) => {
      console.log(randomDocument);
    });
});
```

You can also use countDocuments(), but estimatedDocumentCount() is recommended for performance.

I prefer this method due to getting one document instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the total number of documents in collection.
2. Define a random number between 1 and the total number of documents.
3. Get a document and skip that random number.

```
const total = await model.countDocuments();
const skip = Math.floor(Math.random() * total) + 1;
const randomDoc = await model.findOne({}).skip(skip).exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

command which gives 3 random documents:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([{$sample:{size: 3}}])
```

express line to get 4 random documents. i think it works in the latest versions of mongo.

```js
db.aggregate([{$sample:{size: 4}}])
```

see [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) for further info