# How to find random record in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

How can I find random records in MongoDB?

I found multiple articles here on StackOverflow, but I couldn't understand them.
Like for example:

```
db.yourCollection.find().limit(-1).skip(yourRandomNumber).next()
```

How would I execute it in my code? (collection is `User`)

```
User.findOne(RANDOM PLAYER).then(result) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: im struggeling with  Users.findOne().skip(rand).then(function(result) { @Yashua

Comment: @maria I've posted a detailed answer

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644545/random-document-from-a-collection-in-mongoose

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The idea behind getting a random record is to query all the matching records but just get one. This is what `findOne()` does without any criteria given.

Then you will want to pick a random entry in all the possible matches. This is done by:

1. Find out how many possible entries there could be - we use `count()` on the collection for this. Note that, as mentioned in comments, `count` is deprecated in version 4 and one should use [estimatedDocumentCount](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/#db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount) or [countDocuments](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/#db.collection.countDocuments) instead. The different lies in precision/memory usage amongst other things. Here's a [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53542003/how-accurate-is-mongodbs-estimated-count-query) post discussing it a bit.
2. Come up with a random number within our count.
3. Use `skip()` to "skip" to the desired match and return that.

Here's a snippet as modified from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28331323/856498):

```
// Get the count of all users
User.count().exec(function (err, count) {

  // Get a random entry
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count)

  // Again query all users but only fetch one offset by our random #
  User.findOne().skip(random).exec(
    function (err, result) {
      // Tada! random user
      console.log(result) 
    })
})
```

Comment: Exactlly what I was looking for. Thank you !

Comment: nice work!! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: count() - collection.count is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. Use Collection.countDocuments or Collection.estimatedDocumentCount instead.

Comment: What about using   `const testimonial = await Model.aggregate().sample(2)` ? [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-sample)

Answer (score 0):

To get random document(s) from mongodb by using mongoose.

```
    limitrecords=10;

    function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
      return Math.ceil(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }

    var userschema = new Schema({
      name: String
    });

    User = mongoose.model('User', userschema);

    User.count({your_query},function(err,count){

       var skipRecords = getRandomArbitrary(1, count-limitrecords);

       query.skip(skipRecords); // Random Offset

       query.exec(function(err,result){
         console.log(result);  // 10 random users 
       });

    });
```

This is an example for 10 random records, you can set "limitrecords" according to your requirement.

Thanks!

Comment: `ReferenceError: query is not defined` - where are you setting query from?

Comment: Luke: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query
That is a query. So something like `User.find()` or `User.where({ name: 'vonderful' })`.

Comment: Heads up. That this answer returns a random start of the find but the sequence will always be the same. Original: [ 1 2 3 4 5 ] with limitrecords=3, possible returns: [ 1, 2, 3 ],  [2 3 4 ],[ 3 4 5 ]