# How to find or get random records or documents in a mongodb using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have tried finding a way of getting random records/documents in a MongoDB using mongoose without success.

[The solution I found here failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277670/how-to-find-random-record-in-mongoose) which is four(4) years ago didn't solve my problem because it tends to skip some documents based on the generated random number.

**The problem** is that if you have 3 documents in the db and the random number generated is 3, doing the  following as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277670/how-to-find-random-record-in-mongoose):

```
User.findOne().skip(random).exec(
    function (err, result) {
      // Tada! random user
      console.log(result) 
    })
```

...will make `.skip(3)` to skip the whole three documents and return [] ( 404 error).

What I wanted was to shuffle record any time I do `User.find()`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this problem

```
const users = await User.find().limit(50); // limit can be any number, each time you make a request, values will always be returned if have records is in your MongoDB

const randomUsers = users.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

return res.status(200).send({ success: true, message: 'success: random users', data: randomUsers });
```

Any time you make a request, you are sure of getting a record but shuffled, reordered, or randomised the list based on the random number generated.

Trust this sovled a similar problem for you!