# mongodb get random by low amount of counts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im currently counting users, and finding a random one:

```
 Users.count(function(error,count) {
        console.log("calculating random ");
        console.log("players: " + count);
       var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * count) + 1;
        console.log("random is " + rand);

        Users.findOne().skip(rand).then(function(playerresult) {
            console.log("FINAL RESULT: " + playerresult);
           return resolve(playerresult);
        });

    });
}
```

in this example output:

```
  getting the random player
calculating random 
players: 2
random is 2
FINAL RESULT: null
got the result! to show!
```

In the debug it says it exist 2 documents, and random is two, but it returns zero. how can i make the randomness work even on low amount of documents? have i done something wrong ?

Comment: If you have 2 players, and you skip 2, you've skipped over all of them.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644545/random-document-from-a-collection-in-mongoose

Comment: i see that @robertklep but how could i make sure it would be atleast 1 result?

Comment: @maria remove the `+ 1` when determining the value of `rand`

Comment: thanks @robertklep  could we chat?

Comment: @maria sure! Not sure how to start one though.

Comment: i will try to start one now.

Comment: @robertklep http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122500/mongo-questions