# How to get random records using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I found [mongoose-random](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-random) package to get a JSON array of random records using mongoose.

I want to get three random records with a specific field. I read the documentation, but I still didn't find any solution. The following code doesn't work.

```
app.get('/get/random/song/:language/:gender', function (req, res) {

    var fields = {lang: req.params.language, gender: req.params.gender};
    var filter = {}
    var options = {skip: 3, limit: 3};
    Song.findRandom(filter, fields, options, function (err, songs) {
        res.json(songs);
    });
    
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random record from MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824157/random-record-from-mongodb)

Comment: possible dupicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644545/random-document-from-a-collection-in-mongoose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nowadays you could use `aggregate` , like this :

`this.aggregate([ { $match: { "condition1" : "to_match" , "condition2" : "to_match" } } , { $sample: { size : 3 } } ]);`

Where the `$sample` size is the number of random rows you'll get